# Setas do teclado em QT

Tags: qt, teclado

Quando queremos usar as setas do Teclado em C++ usamos as bibliotecas Ncurses ou conio.h, dependendo do sistema operacional.

Mas existe uma maneira de fazer isso usando as bibliotecas do QT ?

Comment: Sim: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html. "*Key events are sent to the widget with keyboard input focus when keys are pressed or released.*" Exemplo aqui: http://programmingexamples.wikidot.com/qt-events#toc3

Comment: conio.h não é C++.  É um legado muito antigo do MS-DOS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, usando `QKeySequence` com `QAction` por exemplo se necessitar disparar um `SLOT` especifico, exemplo no `MainWindow.h` teria o seguinte slot:

```
private slots:
    void meuEvento();
```

E no `MainWindow.cpp` teria isto:

```
#include <QKeySequence>
#include <QAction>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QKeySequence seq = QKeySequence(tr("Ctrl+S"));

    QAction *act = new QAction(this);

    QObject::connect(act, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(meuEvento()));

    this->addAction(act);

    act->setShortcut(seq);
}

void MainWindow::meuEvento()
{
    qDebug() << "TESTE";
}
```

No exemplo o terceiro parâmetro é o `this` de `QObject::connect`, que se refere a classe aonde esta o slot `meuEvento`, mas é claro que pode apontar slots de outros objetos.

Você pode usar uma string com sinal de `+` como separador `QKeySequence(tr("Ctrl+S"))` ou usar as [constantes](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qkeysequence.html#StandardKey-enum), exemplo:

```
QKeySequence(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_S);
```

Mais constantes: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qkeysequence.html#standard-shortcuts

---

Eu também desenvolvi uma pequena biblioteca para uso mais pessoal, mas que compartilho que visa *"diminuir um pouco a escrita de código"*:

- https://github.com/brcontainer/qt-helper

Faça o download em https://github.com/brcontainer/qt-helper/archive/master.zip, então extraia a parte que lhe é importante, no caso a pasta que será usada é a:

```
/application/keysequence/
```

Nela existem 3 arquivos:

- `keysequence.h`
- `keysequence.cpp`
- `keysequence.pri`

Coloque a pasta `keysequence` dentro do teu projeto e adicione isto ao seu `.pro`

```
include($$PWD/keysequence/keysequence.pri)
```

Então se deseja adicionar um evento ao `Mainwindow`, faça isto:

```
#include "keysequence.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    KeySequence::widget(this, "Ctrl+W", this, SLOT(meuEvento()));
}
```

Se for a um widget especifico faça isto:

```
ui->setupUi(this);

KeySequence::widget(ui->textField, "Ctrl+W", this, SLOT(meuEvento()));
```

> Nos exemplos Ctrl+W executando o evento, pode customizar isto ou usar [`QKeySequence::StandardKey`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qkeysequence.html#StandardKey-enum)

Comment: @Bacco e eu achando que era confusão minha e que eu estava enferrujado kkkkkkkkk, faz quase um ano que não trabalho de verdade com Qt. Blz, vou fazer também sobre QKeyEvent! :D Até mais tarde

Comment: Pra variar, muito bom! :) +1

Comment: Eu recebendo um elogio do @LuizVieira devo estar sonhando, significa que estou no caminho certo! :D muito obrigado!

Comment: Ah, para com isso! Se eu elogiei, é porque vc mereceu na minha opinião. :)